# How can I achieve to have a unique key for every <td>

Tags: reactjs

How can I achieve to have a unique key for every 
Do I need to create UUIDs before saving my data for every product?

```
objectId":"00163E6CDDFC1EEA97DF0965781E400F","ID":
product1":"F103_SURFACELAPTOP_15","product1Quantity":,
"product2":"F101_MACBOOKPRO_16","product2Quantity":,
"product3":"F102_MACBOOKPRO_13","product3Quantity":,
"product4":"F104_SURFACELAPTOP_13", "product4Quantity":
```

This is how my table looks

```
         <tr>
            {value.map((item, index) =>
              <>
                <td key={index}>{index + 1}</td>
                <td key={index}>{item.ID}</td>
                <td key={index}>{item.product1}</td>
                <td key={index}>{item.product1Quantity}</td>
                <td key={index}>{item.product2}</td>
                <td key={index}>{item.product2Quantity}</td>
                <td key={index}>{item.product3}</td>
                <td key={index}>{item.product3Quantity}</td>
                <td key={index}>{item.product4}</td>
                <td key={index}>{item.product4Quantity}</td>
              </>
            )}
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this that you have done will give you unique key, React documentation is not suggesting to use this approach. Try to find something that is unique for every component that you are maping for rendering, or if you do not have something like that, than you can use library for uuid

```
npm install uuid  or yarn add uuid
```

then inside component import library `import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';`

and then inside mapping do this

```
key={uuidv4()}
```

Comment: This would have worse performance than using the index. Every time the map function is run, all items would rerender.

Comment: This is not how a key should be used. Its purpose is to distinguish react elements so that it can update/add/remove the correct one. This method will assign a new key each render since the function call is inline. For this case it would only be inefficient, but if you were to do this when rendering a component it would cause a full unmount/re-mount each render.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to point out is that you're providing the key to the wrong elements. You need to assign a unique key to the *root* element as you are mapping. In this case it is the `<>` fragment. You'll need to use the full name like this:

```js
{value.map((item, index) =>
  <React.Fragment key={yourKey}>
    ...
  </React.Fragment>
)}
```

The next thing to point out is that using the index of the array as the key is [discouraged](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

React will actually automatically use the index to assign the key if not specified, you will just get a warning in the console.

I see you have an ID for the item. I would suggest using that:

```
{value.map((item, index) =>
  <React.Fragment key={item.ID}>
    ...
  </React.Fragment>
)}
```

If that ID isn't always unique, or isn't always present - first try to find something else that is. If all else fails, you can fall back to using the index as a last resort. Just be aware that if the order of the array changes you may get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that key is used by React to optimise rendering of items in a list whenever the items are updated. What you probably need is:

```
{value.map((item, index) =>
  <tr key={item.ID}>
    <td>{index + 1}</td>
    <td>{item.ID}</td>
    <td>{item.product1}</td>
    <td>{item.product1Quantity}</td>
    <td>{item.product2}</td>
    <td>{item.product2Quantity}</td>
    <td>{item.product3}</td>
    <td>{item.product3Quantity}</td>
    <td>{item.product4}</td>
    <td>{item.product4Quantity}</td>
  </tr>
)}
```

If `ID` is unique across items, it's a good candidate for key for an item row.